# Evil Buddha, anyone?

Tags: mindfulness

If a person practices mindfulness and concentration with great success but doesn't care about Noble Eightfold Path, is there a possibility of creating so to say "Evil (or at least immoral) Buddha"?
Were there any historical examples of such people?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but what do you think an "evil Buddha" is, or does, or says etc., what are their characteristics? It sounds like "dry water" to me, an oxymoron. -- I don't understand what the question is asking/describing.

Comment: There are forms of Buddhism which do not focus on the eightfold path, but other things like six paramitas. Are you talking about the eightfold specifically, or do you just mean the buddhist path in general? Even if you meant the latter, the concept of an evil Buddha makes no sense as all Buddhas are lacking self delusion and are incapable of immorality.

Comment: An example could be Buddha's own cousin who was highly accomplished in meditation and the path but had jealousy and ill will left over. He tried to kill the Buddha multiple times.

Comment: Even if the history calls a Buddha, evil , there is no self in it ,only ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

Buddha means the person who has already eradicated attachment, aversion and ignorance. Hence there is no evil Buddha's. The Buddhist term for them is the "Mara" the opposite of Buddha.
The people who practice mindfulness and concentration without the backing of Noble Eightfold Path is called "wrong mindfulness" or "[Miccha](https://suttacentral.net/define/micch%C4%81?lang=en) Sati and Miccha Samadhi"

Comment: Well, these people can be not religious at all. ;) But I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly anecdotal, but... Behring Breivik allegedly had a great interest in mindfulness meditation.

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/belief/2012/may/22/anders-behring-breivik-meditation

It is no coincidence that Sila is such a central aspect of buddhism. You can't reach buddhahood without it:

> One makes an effort for the abandoning of wrong view & for entering into right view: This is one's right effort. One is mindful to abandon wrong view & to enter & remain in right view: This is one's right mindfulness. Thus these three qualities — right view, right effort, & right mindfulness — run & circle around right view.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html

Answer (score 0):

I am from the Theravada perspective.

There is only one Buddha who opened the path, everyone else is a follower.

Without the 8 fold path, You can go all the way to 4th Jhana and beyond (which is worthless) if you want.
Reaching the 4th you create enormous power and ability to do great things. 
In the ancient times there has been many great sages who did amazing good things as well as some has destroyed whole cities with the population with their single thoughts(according to the scriptures).
Yes, they can be Evil.

However, here is the catch, if you are naturally a bad person you can never reach a Jhana. Because the “mechanism” works in the opposite direction.
You need to have a well disciplined and purified inner mind to reach a Jhana.

If you do any evil things after your skills development, it will automatically undo everything what you have achieved. How fast it happens is depending on the level of achievement and severity of the evil deeds.

Almost always, if someone knows the 8 fold path and reaching this Jhanic level, will never miss the chance.

It is like you practice throughout your whole life for Olympic gold medal and you are reaching the finishing line ahead of everyone else. But you turn back a couple of feet before and go shoot your legs.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it's said, the concepts 'good' and 'evil' in the Western world don't translate well to the Buddhist worldview. What Westerners consider 'evil' and 'good' Buddhists see as 'karmic': caught in a pattern that is deleterious (in the first case) or beneficial but un-liberated (in the second). Fully awakened beings are neither good nor evil. Such people are merely free of the compulsions and aversions that would drive them to commit acts others might find problematic.

Remember that the assertion of good or evil is always subjective — people we call 'evil' will almost certainly consider themselves 'good'; the eternal misunderstanding — but being *awake* means losing the subject that makes such assertions.

Answer (score 0):

'Right mindfulness' ('samma sati') in Buddhism is defined as follows:

> ‘I will protect myself,’ bhikkhus: thus should the establishments of mindfulness be practised. ‘I will protect others,’ bhikkhus: thus should the establishments of mindfulness be practised. Protecting oneself, bhikkhus, one protects others; protecting others, one protects oneself.
>
> [SN 47.19](https://suttacentral.net/sn47.19/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true)

> mindful, rid of covetousness and displeasure towards the world
>
> [MN 10](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin)

> One is mindful to abandon wrong action & to enter & remain in right action: This is one's right mindfulness.
>
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

> Just as a citadel has a gatekeeper who is astute, competent, and intelligent, who keeps strangers out and lets known people in, in the same way a noble disciple is mindful. They have utmost mindfulness and alertness, and can remember and recall what was said and done long ago. A noble disciple with mindfulness as their gatekeeper gives up the unskillful and develops the skillful, they give up the blameworthy and develop the blameless, and they keep themselves pure.
>
> [AN 7.67](https://suttacentral.net/an7.67/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin)

Therefore, in Buddhism, it is impossible to have Right Mindfulness and perform evil actions because the word 'mindfulness' in Buddhism means to remember to not perform evil.